# Total Number of Leaves of same type in a month

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables name EmployeeInfo and Leave and I am storing the values that which employee have taken which type of leave in month and how many times.
I am trying to calculate the number of leaves of same type but I'm stuck at one point for long time.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Leave'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [Leave];
END;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('EmployeeInfo'))
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [EmployeeInfo];
END;
GO

CREATE TABLE [EmployeeInfo] (
[EmpID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[EmployeeName] VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE [Leave] (
    [LeaveID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [LeaveType] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [DateFrom] VARCHAR(255),
    [DateTo] VARCHAR(255),
    [Approved] Binary,
    [EmpID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeInfo(EmpID)
);
GO


INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo([EmpID], [EmployeeName]) VALUES
(1, 'Marcia'),
(2, 'Lacey'),
(3, 'Fay'),
(4, 'Mohammad'),
(5, 'Mike')


INSERT INTO Leave([LeaveID],[LeaveType],[DateFrom],[DateTo], [Approved], [EmpID]) VALUES
(1, 'Annual Leave','2018-01-08 04:52:03','2018-01-10 20:30:53', 1, 1),
(2, 'Sick Leave','2018-02-10 03:34:41','2018-02-14 04:52:14', 0, 2),
(3, 'Casual Leave','2018-01-04 11:06:18','2018-01-05 04:11:00', 1, 3),
(4, 'Annual Leave','2018-01-17 17:09:34','2018-01-21 14:30:44', 0, 4),
(5, 'Casual Leave','2018-01-09 23:31:16','2018-01-12 15:11:17', 1, 3),
(6, 'Annual Leave','2018-02-16 18:01:03','2018-02-19 17:16:04', 1, 2)
```

My query which I have tried so far look something like this.

```
SELECT Info.EmployeeName, Leave.LeaveType, SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, Leave.DateFrom, Leave.DateTo)) [#OfLeaves], DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom)

FROM EmployeeInfo Info, Leave

WHERE Info.EmpID = Leave.EmpID AND Approved = 1  

GROUP BY Info.EmployeeName, Leave.LeaveType, [Leave].[DateFrom], [Leave].[DateTo]
```

And the record like given below

```
EmployeeName   LeaveType         #OfLeaves   MonthNumber
-------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
Fay            Casual Leave      1           1
Fay            Casual Leave      3           1
Lacey          Annual Leave      3           2
Marcia         Annual Leave      2           1
```

I want the record to look like this

```
    EmployeeName   LeaveType         #OfLeaves   MonthNumber
    -------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
    Fay            Casual Leave      4           1
    Lacey          Annual Leave      3           2
    Marcia         Annual Leave      2           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just need small adjustment with your query in the `GROUP BY` clause. Instead of grouping them by `[Leave].[DateFrom]` and `[Leave].[DateTo]` which causes the row to be separated, you need to group it with the calculated column that uses *datepart*.

```
SELECT  Info.EmployeeName, 
        Leave.LeaveType, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, Leave.DateFrom, Leave.DateTo)) [#OfLeaves], 
        DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom)
FROM    EmployeeInfo Info
        INNER JOIN Leave
          ON Info.EmpID = Leave.EmpID
WHERE   Approved = 1  
GROUP   BY Info.EmployeeName, 
         Leave.LeaveType, 
         DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom)  -- <<<< change only this part
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b988/5).

I have also modified the syntax into `ANSI` format.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: I didn't do that. I'm curious too why would somebody do that as this is simplest and easiest answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify existing query due to some constraint, this might work:

```
Select iq.EmployeeName, iq.LeaveType, SUM(iq.#OfLeaves) as #OfLeaves, iq.MonthNumber 
From (
    SELECT  Info.EmployeeName, Leave.LeaveType, SUM(DATEDIFF(Day, Leave.DateFrom, Leave.DateTo)) [#OfLeaves], DatePart(MONTH, Leave.DateFrom) as MonthNumber
    FROM    EmployeeInfo Info, Leave
    WHERE   Info.EmpID = Leave.EmpID AND Approved = 1  
    GROUP BY Info.EmployeeName, Leave.LeaveType, [Leave].[DateFrom], [Leave].[DateTo]
)iq
group by iq.EmployeeName, iq.LeaveType, iq.MonthNumber
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense too.